# HTTP POST request with JSON Reading in Multiple Classes of Students and Varying Numbers of Assignments and Grades

Tags: java, json, http, post

I have been attempting to create an HTTP POST request that uses JSON for the purpose of sending information from a Java gradebook application to a Rails web-based application that displays those grades in the form of a report to students. This is what I have so far.

Ultimately, I want to send more than just one student's information.  Furthermore, each student might have anywhere from 0 to 50 assignments, descriptions of the assignments, as well as grades for those assignments.  On top of that there will be multiple classes/courses of students. All this information needs to be "read in" to the JSON object.  Does anyone have any suggestions about how I could modify this code so that I could send all that data rather than the data for just one student as is shown below (as well as more than one class/course)?

```
public class HTTPPostRequestWithSocket {

    public void sendRequest(){

        try {
             JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
             obj.put("instructorName", "Smith");
             obj.put("courseName", "Biology 101");
             obj.put("studentName1", "John Doe");
             obj.put("studentNumber", new Integer(100));
             obj.put("assignment1", "Test 1");
             obj.put("gradeAssignment1", new Double("95.3"));

             String hostname = "nameofthewebsite.com";

             InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
             Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);
             String path = "/nameofapp";

             // Send headers
            BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new   OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
            wr.write("POST "+path+" HTTP/1.0rn");

            wr.write("Content-Length: "+obj.length()+"rn");
            wr.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencodedrn");
             wr.write("rn");

            // Send parameters
             obj.writeJSONString(wr);
             wr.flush();

            // Get response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                }

            wr.close();
            rd.close();
            socket.close();
            }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
         }
}
```

Comment: Use Content-Type :application/json

Comment: Sorry if I'm a little dense.  But you're recommending to change the line "wr.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencodedrn");" to "wr.write("Content-Type: application/json");"

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis i think you need to use Arrays, JsonArray object or array of json objects, based on the case, for each student, each student json object has student info + an array of courses with grades... etc you can create a class to hold this information and use Gson to serialize it.

Comment: A nested loop consisting of an outer loop of classes and inner loop of students?

Comment: Could be... Imagine each item (student) as object that has attributes: name , age, year... And courses ...Courses[] which is array of objects of type Course... Then init and fill a students array and Gson serialize it

Comment: So are you saying that there would be a JSON array of courses and embedded within each of those courses an array of student objects?